# Toggle in jQuery on form loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am moving from 1 page to other in html, passing the form elements and their values.

In creating the values I show/hide certain elements based on the need.
Now when on next page I click EDIT, I come back to this page but the view is the default view.

How can I modify the view using a jQuery/javascript from default to something based on the values saved, on form re-loading for edit?

```
if(jQuery('#UPLOADFILE').prop('checked') == true) {

    jQuery('.FILEVIEW').show();

    jQuery('.OTHERVIEW').hide();

}
```

Could you please give me a js example how to activate the above code. Everytime I re-load the page this piece of code doesn't execute, although #UPLOADFILE is checked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how you are loading the page? using ajax ?

Comment: I am using perl and .esp page to do that

Comment: but nevetheless I will have values in Jquery elements and store them in the same place. Basically I am reconstructing the page with the same values.

Comment: You either have to pass all the values via URL parameter, or you save them locally in the browsers [localstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and fetch them from there when the user opens the page. In both cases you have to pre-fill the form with the data via jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You know, instead of using JQuery, you can always save it to a database and then edit it to update the values. Seeing that you're trying to save something anyways(after you edit it, in my understanding), why not save what you entered and then edit it if you want to? Simplifies things a lot, imo. Just saying.

Comment: I second this. It saves a lot of unnecessary client side pollution of logic.

Comment: yeah I understand, but the parent page doesn't work that way.

Comment: Also, how could I toggle views everytime I load form? Im having trouble changing default view options when I click Edit on second page

Answer (score 0):

I would go with @Lloyd Francis answer but in case you don't want to do DB save and fetch then you have following options on client side.

Save the state in

1. Cookies
2. Pass the date in URL between pages ( not recommended )
3. Local Storage http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

In the document ready event handle the logic appropriately.

Comment: Hi Vishal, exactly what I am trying to do. Could you share an example piece of code to show how to correctly handle the form event? And also help me know why my code above doesn't work?

Comment: i cannot give you any code because I have no idea of your code. The link I have provided in the answer tell you how to use local-storage. So you basically store the state in local storage before going to the next page and if user is redirected to the first page, first read the value from the local storage to see if a state already exists. If yes then load the required view else load the default view.